# net.java.util.tagValue : Not resolvable

Tags: java

In my program, I am trying to import below classes but there comes a compile time error for this. Am I missing any jar there ? If yes, then which jar I am missing. Please help me.


"import net.java.util.TagValue;"

I am writing this in eclipse

Comment: Possibly: http://code.google.com/p/fixparser/

Comment: Looks like you need [fixparser](https://code.google.com/p/fixparser/) library.

Comment: I need jar for this. I checked on the same link as you mentioned but that page is not opening. Please let me know where can I get jar file for this parser. Please share the link with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search on the net shows that `net.java.util.TagValue` class belongs to [fixparser](https://code.google.com/p/fixparser/) library. Make sure that this library is in your classpath when working on your project.

Comment: @Vaibhav if this post solved your problem, make sure to mark it as the answer by clicking the check below the up and down arrows. You should also do this for all your other questions (just in case a post solves your problem).